# Having Problem with my PHP Code and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I need some help
Whenever I input all the information and wanted to click submit, it always alert me "You already submit before" but it was the first time i entered the information. So there shouldn't be any duplicate values.
And the data itself also didn't post into my phpmyadmin database.

Secondly, i added the addclass("error") and removeclass ('error') in the javascript. However only those selection questions will show the red error border line while text input questions didn't show the error border line even though it is wrong

I have spent days to investigate it but still couldn't solve it.

```
My index.php file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Refund Request Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
<!--    <script src="form.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>



<div class="container">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <div class="form-container">
        <span style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 0px;"><br>
            <center>
                <h1>
                    Refund Request Form
                </h1>
            </center>

        </span>
        <form method="post" id="form" name="form">

            <label for="school_num">School Number: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="school_num" type="text" placeholder="Enter your School Number" name="school_num"  maxlength="50">

            <label for="name">Full Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name in Capital as per IC" name="name"  maxlength="50">

            <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" name="email"  maxlength="50">

            <label for="ic_num">IC Number: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="ic_num" type="number" placeholder="Enter your IC Number (without dash)" name="ic_num" data-parsley-length="[12,12]"  maxlength="12">


            <label for="nts">Event1 Refund Amount: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select id="nts" placeholder="-" name="nts" onchange="sum()"  >
                <option value = "-" selected>-</option>
                <option value = "0" >0</option>
                <option value = "80">80</option>
                <option value = "100">100</option>
                <option value = "110">110</option>
                <option value = "110">120</option>
            </select>

            <label for="pesta">Event2  Refund Amount: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select id="pesta" placeholder="" name="pesta" onchange="sum()"  >
                <option value = "-" selected>-</option>
                <option value = "0" >0</option>
                <option value = "100">100</option>
                <option value = "360">360</option>
                <option value = "450">450</option>
                <option value = "460">460</option>
                <option value = "535">535</option>
                <option value = "540">540</option>
            </select>

            <label for="remarks">Remarks:</label>
            <textarea id="remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="Type your remarks here" rows="5" maxlength="6000"></textarea>

            <label style="border-bottom:1px dotted grey; padding-top: 30px;" colspan="2"></label>

            <label for="refund" class="refund" style="color:#faa51a;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 500; font-size: 150%;width: 30%">Refund Total: </label>
             <input id="refund"  class="refund1" value="0" readonly style="border:none;color:#faa51a;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 150%;width: 20%">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" id="refund" name="refund" class="refund1" value="0" > -->

            <input class="button-primary"  name="submit" id="submit" role="button" type="button" onClick="validateForm()" value="Submit">
<!--            <input type="button" class="button-primary"  type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" role="button"  value="Submit">-->

        </form>

        <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
            <h3>Submitted the form successfully!</h3>
            <p> We will get back to you soon. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //this calculates values automatically
        sum();
        $("#nts, #pesta").on("keydown keyup", function() {
            sum();
        });
    });

    function sum() {
        var nts = document.getElementById('nts').value;
        var pesta = document.getElementById('pesta').value;
        var refundTotal = parseInt(nts) + parseInt(pesta);
        if (!isNaN(refundTotal)) {
            document.getElementById('refund').value ="RM " + refundTotal;
        }
    }

    function validateEmail($email) {
        var re = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        if ($email == '' || !re.test($email))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateAlphabet($account_name){
        var letters = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        if($account_name.value.match(letters))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // function validateNumber (){
    //
    // }


    function validateForm() {
        $('#submit').disable=true;
        var valid = true;
        var error_msg="";

        //school number
        if($('#school_num').val()=='' && $.trim($('#school_num').val()).length<=0 ){
            error_msg+=("Please insert your school number\n");
            $('#school_num').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            $('#school_num').removeClass("error");  
        }

        //name
        if($('#name').val()==''){
            error_msg+=("Please insert your name\n");
            $('#name').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            $('#name').removeClass("error");
        }

        //email
        if($('#email').val()==''){
            error_msg+=("Please insert your email address\n");
            $('#email').addClass("error");
            valid=false;

        }else{
            if(validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)==false){
                //console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
                error_msg+=("Invalid email address, Please fill in the correct email\n");
                $('#email').addClass("error");
                valid=false;

            }else{
                $('#email').removeClass("error");
            }
        }

        //ic number
        if($('#ic_num').val()==''){
            error_msg+=("Please insert your IC Number (without dash)\n");
            $('#ic_num').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            if(!$.isNumeric($("#ic_num").val())){
                //console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
                error_msg+=("Invalid IC Number - should be numbers only (no dash)\n");
                $('#ic_number').addClass("error");
                valid=false;

            }else{
                $('#ic_number').removeClass("error");
            }
        }

        //school
        if($('#school').val()=='-'){
            error_msg+=("Please select your school\n");
            $('#school').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            $('#school').removeClass("error");
        }

        //nts
        if($('#nts').val()=='-'){
            error_msg+=("Please select your NTS refund amount\n");
            $('#nts').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            $('#nts').removeClass("error");
        }

        //pesta
        if($('#pesta').val()=='-'){
            error_msg+=("Please select your PESTA refund amount\n");
            $('#pesta').addClass("error");
            valid=false;
        }else{
            $('#pesta').removeClass("error");
        }

        if(error_msg!=""){
            alert(error_msg);
        }
        if(valid){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'form_ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'action':'check_duplicate',
                    'school_num':$('#school_num').val(),
                    'name':$('#name').val(),
                    'email':$('#email').val(),
                    'school':$('#school').val(),
                    'nts':$('#nts').val(),
                    'pesta':$('#pesta').val(),
                    'refund':$('#refund').val(),
                },
                error: function() {
                },
                before:function(){

                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.is_duplicated==0){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'form_ajax.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                'action':'submit_form',
                                'school_num':$('#school_num').val(),
                            },

                            before:function(){

                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#submit').disable=false;

                                if(data.status==1){
                                    alert(data.message);
                                    $('#success_message').show()
                                    //TOOD: Clear all input
                                    $('#school_num').val(''),
                                    $('#name').val(''),
                                    $('#email').val(''),
                                    $('#school').val(''),
                                    $('#nts').val(''),
                                    $('#pesta').val(''),
                                    $('#refund').val('')
                                }else{
                                    alert(data.message);
                                    $('#error_message').show()
                                }
                            },
                            error: function() {
                            },
                        });
                        //TOOD: Clear all input
                    $('#school_num').val(''),
                    $('#name').val(''),
                    $('#email').val(''),
                    $('#school').val(''),
                    $('#nts').val(''),
                    $('#pesta').val(''),
                    $('#refund').val('')
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('You already submit before');
                    }
                },
            });

        }else{
            $('#submit').disable=false;
        }

    }



</script>
</html>
```

```
My form_ajax.php file
<?php

//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['action']=='submit_form'){
    require "config.php";
    require "common.php";
    $statement=false;
    $new_student = array(
        "school_num"     => $_POST['school_num'],
        "name"           => $_POST['name'],
        "email"          => $_POST['email'],
        "ic_num"         => $_POST['ic_num'],
        "school"         => $_POST['school'],
        "nts"            => $_POST['nts'],
        "pesta"          => $_POST['pesta'],
        "remarks"        => $_POST['remarks'],
        "refund"         => $_POST['refund']
    );

    try{
        //#1 Open Connection
        $connection = new PDO ($dsn,$username,$password,$options);
        //#2 Prepare Sql QUERY
        $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO details (school_num,name, email, ic_num,school,nts,pesta,remarks,refund,date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
        $statement ->bindParam(1,$_POST['school_num'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindParam(2,$_POST['name'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindParam(3,$_POST['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindParam(4,str_replace($_POST['ic_num'], '-', ''),PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement ->bindParam(5,$_POST['school'],PDO::PARAM_STR);;
        $statement ->bindParam(6,$_POST['nts'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement ->bindParam(7,$_POST['pesta'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement ->bindParam(8,$_POST['remarks'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindParam(9,$_POST['refund'],PDO::PARAM_INT);


        //$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'Your information has been saved');
        echo json_encode($return_message);

    }   catch (PDOException $error){
        $return_message=array('status'=>0,'message'=>'Sorry we cannot save your information');
        echo json_encode($return_message);
    }
}

if( $_POST['action']=='check_duplicate'){
    require "config.php";
    require "common.php";
    $statement=false;


    try{
        //#1 Open Connection
        $connection = new PDO ($dsn,$username,$password,$options);
        //#2 Prepare Sql QUERY
        $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT details.school_num FROM details");
        $statement->bindParam(':school_num', $_POST ['school_num'], PDO::PARAM_STR);


        //$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->fetchAll();

        $return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'there is duplicate');
        echo json_encode($return_message);

    }catch (PDOException $error){
        $return_message=array('status'=>0,'message'=>'no duplicate');
        echo json_encode($return_message);
    }

}
```

Comment: `console.log(data);` or watch the response in your network tab. Does it contain `is_duplicated`? It's not listed in your PHP code at all, so I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 0):

In your code php does not return the **is_duplicated** variable. Therefore, **data.is_duplicated** is always **undefined** in javascript. That's why result of if check *if(data.is_duplicated==0)* will always false, because **undefined** not equal to **0**.

try to replace this code

```
$return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'there is duplicate');
```

to this

```
$return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'there is duplicate', 'is_duplicated' => 1);
```

and here

```
$return_message=array('status'=>0,'message'=>'no duplicate');
```

to this

```
$return_message=array('status'=>0,'message'=>'no duplicate', 'is_duplicated' => 0);
```

**P.S.**
By the way, why you don't check what statement has? I guess is not correct.

```
//$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$statement->fetchAll();

$return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'there is duplicate');
echo json_encode($return_message);
```

should be

```
//$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
if (empty($results)) {
    $duplicate = 0;
} else {
    $duplicate = 1;
}

$return_message=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'there is duplicate', 'is_duplicated' = $duplicate);
echo json_encode($return_message);
```

**P.P.S.**
To check if there is data in the database is better to use count() and limit=1

GOOD LUCK